# Merge nested array data in single array and get them into root of document

Tags: mongodb, nosql, typegoose

I am struggling with retrieving nested document in root.

below i have a  schema inside it there is a array of tasks in which objects are present,
in those objects there is again an array of assigned objects and in those objects i have solution array.

now i want to merge all solutions in one array and get that solution array in root od document.

Schema -

```
{
  _id: 1,
  tasks: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      assigned: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          solutions: [
            {
              _id: 1,
              name: 'solution 1',
            },
            {
              _id: 2,
              name: 'solution 2',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          _id: 2,
          solutions: [
            {
              _id: 1,
              name: 'solution 1',
            },
            {
              _id: 2,
              name: 'solution 2',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I want to merge all solutions to a single array based on some condition and set that array into new field in root of collection.

```
const order = this.orderModel
      .aggregate([
        { $match: { _id: orderId, student: studentId } },
        {
          $addFields: {
            solutions: {
              $map: {
                input: '$tasks.assigned.solutions',
                as: 's',
                in: '$$s',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ])
      .exec();
```

output i am getting -

```
"solutions": [
        [
            [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "solution 1",
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "_id": 2,
                    "name": "solution 2"
                }
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$project": {
  "solutions": {
    "$reduce": {
      "input": "$tasks",
      "initialValue": [],
      "in": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$$value",
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$$this.assigned",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this.solutions"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
])
```

Explained:

Use $project and two nested $reduce/$concatArrays to join the "solutions" array objects  under the new array field "solutions" in the document root.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DKpxsVsdqQA)

if you want to filter based on some condition you can replace "$$this.solutions" with:

```
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$$this.solutions",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", 1] }
            }
          }
```

will filter only documents with _id:1

see example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pSGYr4Nf2cS)

Comment: can you tell how can i concate that array based on its field's condition. (like solution.verified: true) only add those solutions

Comment: you can use $filter inside the concatenate to have only the necessary elements ...

Comment: add one more playground example using $filter to my answer above ...

Comment: while reducing can i attach sucdoc parent's id in it. Like in solutions can i attach assigned id ?